# How to save/load text files in Objective-C for the iPhone, using UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

How do you save text files permanently to an iPhone? And then be able to open them again in another UITextView?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

To write a NSString to a file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

NSString *str = @"hello world";

[str writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

To load NSString from a file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

And use `text` property of UITextView to set and get NSString.

```
NSString *str = myTextView.text;
myAnotherTextView.text = str;
```

Comment: Thanks taskinoor, there are no errors, but when i click the button linked to retrieving the file, nothing shows up. What's going wrong? How do i print out the file correctly?

Comment: Please check whether the file is saved correctly or not. I forget the iOS simulator directory path for document folder. Please Google for that.

Comment: Dead thread... Google didn't seem to give any working insights

Comment: @TheDeveloper, the simulator path is something like this: `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/`

Comment: I found that the path **did not** end with a / so appending a file name to it it would turn out to be `/path_of_epicness/DocumentsFile.png`

Comment: @TheDeveloper, I am not sure what you are trying to do and what you meant by your last comment. Inside the simulator directory there will be more directory based on installed SDKs. Inside them there will be applications directory, then directory for specific app. These full paths are NOT for using in code, rather they are for checking app bundle contents on a Mac. I am really confused what you are trying to do.

Comment: @taskinoor could you please take a look at this question which requires sharing the file to Files app - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72618990/change-file-name-while-sharing-document-base64-string-not-url-to-files-app