# Objective C, How to parse local XML file in Resources folder?

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have a XML file in resources folder in xcode and I want to parse the XML..
The question is how to get access to the file programmatically? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSXMLParser is an event driven xml parser. You can use it but I tend to like query based parsers better. Lib2Xml.

this will get you started with lib2xml

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

An xml file is the just another text file.  This has info on different ways to load xml files.

[How to save/load text files in Objective-C for the iPhone, using UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100994/how-to-save-load-text-files-in-objective-c-for-the-iphone-using-uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. Two of the most popular: use Cocoa's [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/) class, or use [TouchXML](https://github.com/mrevilme/TouchXML). If you use NSXMLParser, you'll end up creating a delegate for the parser that decides what to do whenever the parser encounters XML tags, data, etc.