# Draw something and copy it on a existing pdf document on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, drawing, edit

I want to make a simple drawing with finger and insert it in a existing pdf file. I don't know at all how begin this feature.

So,first step: make a drawing, second: edit a pdf file and insert the drawing,final: Save the document.

How can I start?
What libraries do you recommend me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details about what you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For drawing you could use this library:
https://github.com/gtmtg/MGDrawingSlate

For creating a PDF i can recommend following this tutorial:
http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/iOS-Create-PDF-using-UIKit

Or you could just create some HTML and genarate a PDF from that using: https://github.com/ocrickard/OCPDFGen

For writing a file you can have a look at:
[How to save/load text files in Objective-C for the iPhone, using UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100994/how-to-save-load-text-files-in-objective-c-for-the-iphone-using-uitextview)