# How can I create session?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, session, appdelegate

I need to session. I couldn't find any thing about this issue. Therefore I used appdelegate global variable, but app global variable not save value long time.

I mean, my aim is login page. I don't want user to sign in many time in my app. How can I realize this approach?

Comment: you can save values in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: check my code really helpful to you...

Answer (score 1):

You could check with NSUserDefaults

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(![defaults boolForKey:@"login"])
     {
         /// view to login or signup what ever
     }
     else
     {
         /// user already logged in
     }
```

Comment: Why third time username and password values are empty?

Answer (score 1):

save the data in NSUserDefaults,

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *username=[defaults objectForKey:@"username"] ;
```

Comment: Someone says don't use NSUserDefauls for password because of it is not safe. Can I use it?

Comment: in that situation you can save the data in NSDocumentary directiory by using files and retrive the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100994/how-to-save-load-text-files-in-objective-c-for-the-iphone-using-uitextview

Comment: Why third time username and password values are empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSUserDefaults for this purpose.
Here's an example for you. Good luck!

```
- (void) createSession:(NSObject *anyObject) {
    //write an object to NSUserDefaults with the key of "session"
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:anyObject forKey:@"session"];

    //persist the value in the store
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (NSObject*) getSession {
    //get an object from NSUserDefaults with the key of "session"
    return [[NSUserDefaults] standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"session"];
}

- (void) exampleUsage {
    NSObject* mySessionObject = [self getSession];
    if (mySessionObject != nil) {
        //i have a session
    } else {
        //i do NOT have a session
    }
}
```

Comment: I used web service so my app re connect service to refresh data so my application keep username and pasword. Is NSUserDefauls safe?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is safe to use if your sandbox is encrypted. This is specified in your Provisioning Profile on the Apple Provisioning Portal. Look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html under the heading Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You must use NSUserDefault To Login Window.

```
NSUserDefaults def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[def setObject:delegate.txtfield1.text forKey:@"UserName"];
[def setObject:delegate.txtfield2.text forKey:@"Password"];
[def synchronize];
```

If you want to retrive the NSUSERDefault data used this code.

```
NSString *UserName=[defaults objectForKey:@"UserName"] ;
NSString *Password=[defaults objectForKey:@"Password"] ;
```

And For Checking the status

```
if(![def boolForKey:@"UserName"])
 {

 }
 else
 {

 }
```

try this one might be helpful to you......

Comment: Someone says don't save username and password in NSUserDefault, use NSURLCredentials, My mind mixed

Comment: NSUserDefault is easy to implement and understand.and i doesen't use NSURL Credentials...

Comment: Hi, 

I implemented your code, I can set and get values, but after second or third push to others view controllers, my NSUserDefaults values removed, why?

Comment: can You please post your detail code what you tried...And NSUSERDefault value are remove after application Unistall App from Device...

Comment: i think you UnInstall App from device and once again load..then NSUserDefault value removed..

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

Comment: viewDidAppeae call only at once try to add your code in ViewDidLoad{}

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSObject *session = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"sessionUsr"];
    if(session != nil && ![session isEqual:@""])
    {
    [self ConnectToService];
    }
}

Comment: When I write my code in viewDidLoad, I get error message like below

nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <...: 0xcda4250>.
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Comment: So I can't use my code in viewDidLoad therefore this error. I can get NSUserDefaults value correctly 2 times, but in third time my session value became empty. How can I solve?

Comment: in my parserDidEnd document code

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.eposta.text forKey:@"sessionUsr"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.sifre.text forKey:@"sessionPass"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: try to creating Default object.. and then [def synchronize];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31567/discussion-between-cdsoft-and-jitendra-deore)